# Does "killed the dog" mean flatulence?

Tags: idioms, idiom-meaning, origin-unknown

I have been using this idiom as a synonym for "passing gas" ever since I heard it in the cult comedy classic, *Kung Pow: Enter the Fist*.

Here's the usage:
[Kung Pow: Killed the Dog](https://youtu.be/JSH_riW7V8s)

I happened to say it recently with someone who had no idea what I meant.

I couldn't find a reference on its origin so I'd love it if someone can provide some background.

Answer (score 3):

As you might have guessed, the quote from the film suggests, that the stench from the flatulence is so bad, it even kills an animal.

As far as I know, this is not a synonym for passing gas, it is just a [movie quote](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Kung_Pow!_Enter_the_Fist). Therefore, I would say that anyone remembering the scene in the movie would understand the idiom. Also, if the idiom is presented in the right context, people might also be able to understand what you are talking about.

For example

> - *[awful stench can be smelled]*
> - You: "Puh, I just had to kill that dog."